# .net core api returns 500 when i make a post request from axios post

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core web api deployed on azure with mssql database which is also deployed on azure.
I try to do a post request from postman and it's successful but when i try to do it inside my react app using axios i get 500 error which has this error message:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT
>   statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_TextWidgets_Users_UserId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "SchoolProjectDB", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

Here is my client side axios code:

```
    var textWidgetData = {
        "text": text,
        "userId": 1,
    }
    const CreateHandler = () => {
        console.log(textWidgetData);
        axios.post("/TextWidget", {textWidgetData}).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
    }
```

Comment: because you want to insert a row that have a field with relation on other table, now your filed (Id) value not in related table, maybe null or other than value in this foreign key check your FK_TextWidgets_Users_UserId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it problem was in {textWidgetData} part. i replaced it with textWidgetData. And it worked. The 500 error message about foreign key fooled me.